# Inserting a value from another table based on the difference of two other column values

Tags: mysql, sql, case, insert-select

I'm trying to add a column value to my current insert/select statement but I'm not sure if I can use a CASE WHEN clause or if I need to do this another way.

Basically I have a phone number column in my main table. I need to insert a number into it from another table, but the other table has 2 different phone number columns depending on the call type. For instance:

```
CALLINGPARTYNO | FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO | CALLTYPE
------------------------------------------------
1234567890        0987654321              1
0987654321        1234567890              2
```

So what I need to do is dictate which number gets put into my phoneNumber column in table 1. If call type is 1, I want to insert the number from the FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO but if call type is 2, I want to insert the number from CALLINGPARTYNO.

Pseudo code if it helps:

```
Insert into table1(phoneNumber)
SELECT case when /*if calltype = 1, then select FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO*/
    ELSE /*if calltype=2 then select CALLINGPARTYNO */ as phoneNumber

from table2;
```

Is there a way to do this with CASE or is there another way? Looking for the most ideal way to do this so that I can add it into a much larger insert statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any syntactic constructs you can use in a select statement in an insert-select statement:

```
INSERT INTO table1(phoneNumber)
SELECT CASE calltype WHEN 1 THEN finallycalledpartyno
                     WHEN 2 THEN callingpartyno
       END
FROM   table2
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Since, I'm doing this in a row with other selected values, can I add ```AS phoneNumber``` to the ```END``` statement?

Comment: @TomN. Yes. Everything inside `CASE ... END` is one big long expression, you can apply a name to it just like you would with any other column.

Comment: @TomN. yes, you can. The entire `case ... end` is a single (albeit complex) expression. Note that adding such an alias would just help you read the query more easily. It has no functional effect (assuming your query doesn't have a bunch of other parts that actually use this alias directly).